# Install R lgmnet package for Mac M1 chip fails

Tags: gfortran, apple-m1, glmnet

I'm trying to install R package lgmnet but failed.

the warning message
'
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [coxnet5dpclean.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/glmnet’
  '

I installed gfortran as instructed in [https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but when I try to run the complier it returns error message:

'(base) MacBook-Pro:~ cheng$  gfortran
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.'

I'm no pro in R or bash, could someone please help or point me to the right posts?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Returning `no input files` is thevexpected behaviour because you indeed did not enter any input files. Plesse understand that this is a programming site, not a support site for your library you are installing. We wil need more details.

Comment: For example, I do not understand thecreason for the path `/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran`. It seems your R wants the compiler in this particular location. Where exactly did you install gfortran? How did you install R? Is some gfortran distribution available directly in R?